# In Excel, Is it possible to check to see if an entire row can be found in another sheet in the same book?

Tags: excel

I basically have two giant data sets in two separate sheets in the same book, The contents are very specific. Each row represents all the many different attributes of a unique item. Parts (columns) of the items in the list may be similar to other items but each is unique and not completely the same (i.e. Item 1 has attributes X, Y, and Z. Item 2 has attributes X, Y, and A instead of Z). I have to cross reference both sheets and check if there are any items that are missing or extraneous. Is there a way to check if an entire row matches another row in another sheet and then print the results (Yes, Item 1 is in Sheet 2)?

Problem that I came into is that just because Item 1 is Item 1 in sheet 1, Item 1 can easily be Item 1002 in sheet 2, so I need to make sure that every component of Item 1 is checked by row for the entire data set each time. I can't figure out how to start this at all. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated. Just to be clear, each item does not have a 'name' and is only defined by it's attributes.

Comment: Can you show some sample data, and sample expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at that very thing this morning.  I my case, I have a unique key to match on.   Here are options I'm considering:

- Iterate through one spreadsheet, locate the matching key in the 2nd worksheet, iterate thru the cells in that row, and highlight the row if it doesn't match exactly.
- Load both sheets into datasets and iterate same as my first option.   I'm guessing it will be much faster.
- Since I'll need to do this regularly, I might dump the data into a hard database and iterate as before.  That could offer me some other options.

I haven't decided on which way to go, but that's what I'm thinking at this point.